# Visual Studio 2015 debugger showing null when object is not null

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

If I run the following (admittedly contrived) program (VS2015, .NET4.6):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestTaskAsync(null).Wait();
        TestTask(null);
    }

    public static async Task TestTaskAsync(
        EqualityComparer<int> comparer)
    {
        comparer = EqualityComparer<int>.Default;

        if (comparer == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("comparer is null");
        }

        Func<int, bool> func = i => comparer.Equals(i, 0);
    }

    public static Task TestTask(
        EqualityComparer<int> comparer)
    {
        comparer = EqualityComparer<int>.Default;

        if (comparer == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("comparer is null");
        }

        Func<int, bool> func = i => comparer.Equals(i, 0);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

then the program does exactly what I expect it to - i.e. it prints nothing to the console.

However, when debugging, the debugger is telling me that `comparer` is null when it is not.

[image]

Note the following:

- The code does not enter the `if` block.
- The two debug values (both pinned and in the watch window) tell me
  that `comparer` is null, even though it does not enter the if block.
- The squiggly line and the greyed out code is telling me that
  `comparer == null` can *never* be true. Which is correct, I think.
- This only happens in the method marked `async`.

Finally, if I remove the line

```
Func<int, bool> func = i => comparer.Equals(i, 0);
```

Then the problem goes away.

(Note. The point of the above program is to illustrate a problem I'm having in code that actually does something useful. This program is not actually expected to do anything.)

**QUESTION**:
Does anyone know what is happening here?

Comment: I think the ultimate proof of whether `comparer` is or not null is to place a breakpoint at `Console.WriteLine("Comparer is null");` The only way you can tell comparer is null is if and only if this breakpoint is triggered. Did you try this as well ?

Comment: forgive my stupidity but you run TestTaskAysnc(null).Wait .. so your comparerer is null. your func should be an else.. as if its null it cant do anything

Comment: @Ververke Yes I tried that - the breakpoint is not triggered. Either way, the screenshot supplied is contradictory.

Comment: @BugFinder - I'm not sure what you're saying. In the screenshot, the "current statement" is the last line in the method. At that point, comparer cannot be, should not be, and *is* not, null. And yet the debugger says it is.

Comment: @BugFinder - also, I mentioned that this is a contrived example of a program. It is not *supposed* to do anything, except illustrate the debugger issue I mentioned.

Comment: TestTaskAsync runs without problems on my pc. In what build-mode are you running this? Maybe a clean and rebuild would help.

Comment: I see the same thing you do; it may well be a bug in Visual Studio. Debug.WriteLine(comparer) writes the expected non-null value. Assigning the comparer to an intermediate variable makes the problem go away, though: 

    var c = comparer;
    Func<int, bool> func = i => c.Equals(i, 0);

Comment: @Adimeus - This is in Debug. And Clean and Rebuild didn't help, unfortunately. Are you definitely using VS2015, because this doesn't happen in 2013?

Comment: @PetterHesselberg - Thanks for the confirmation. And yes, assigning to an intermediate variable works. If this is a bug in VS2015, where would I raise that?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/05/05/the-easiest-way-to-file-bugs-and-send-error-logs-for-visual-studio-2015/

Comment: I'm having the same problem since I updated to VS 2015 U3.  .NET 4.6.  I am hoping a solution or fix is found before I finish recoding to intermediate variables.

Comment: I updated to VS 2017 and am still seeing the problem.  If I single step through the program the values stay instantiated.  If I set a breakpoint, the instantiated variable becomes null.

Comment: I am also seeing this in VS2017 15.4.4 targeting `monoandroid80` with netstandard20 libraries. https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10296

Comment: I have raised https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.VSSDK/issues/18