# Under which conditions an IEnumerable<T> with non-null elements could be enumerated and elements are null?

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

I'm facing a very odd behavior which can be easily described by the following screenshot:

[image: Odd enumerator behavior...]

In summary:

- `createUpdateDeleteCollection.Update` is a `HashSet<TSourceItem>`.
- It has an item and it's not null (as shown in the whole screenshot).

I'm trying to figure out what may be causing this strange behavior.

This is my dev environment:

- Visual Studio 2015 Update 3
- .NET Framework 4.6.2
- Build configuration: **Debug|AnyCPU**.

### Update

I've added this statement throwing an exception inside the `foreach` loop:

```
if (item == null)
     throw new InvalidOperationException("hey");
```

...and the whole exception is never thrown...

Comment: Does this only happen when you're debugging ?

Comment: @user3185569 I'm not really sure. Maybe. I can check this. I'm debugging this as part of fixing a test, and something doesn't get mapped, and then, I found this!

Comment: You know when you enumerate using the debugger, you might have another enumerator other than the one that the `foreach` is using, so you can't fully trust what you're seeing.. You need to evaluate `item` using a quick watch or something.

Comment: are you using it anywhere inside Parallel operations?

Comment: @user3185569 A quickwatch shows that it's null too!

Comment: @MadOX No, but it's within an asynchronous flow, but there's no more than a thread doing this job

Comment: What does your enumerable does? It is evaluated every time it is executed. When it isn't a list or array, it might return different values from your foreach with respect to your debug watch.

Comment: I've added an update... it seems like it's a debugger issue...

Comment: What is the Visual Studio version and the .Net framework version?

Comment: This can happen when `item` is of a type that returns `null` when converting to `TSourceItem`.

Comment: Can you just add a `if (item == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("item is null")` at the top of the loop body?

Comment: @poke Sorry, yes, I can do it.

Comment: @SouvikGhosh It's .NET 4.6.2 and Visual Studio 2015 Update 3

Comment: @poke It's a debugger issue, the whole exception is never thrown...

Comment: That’s super weird then… :/

Comment: Then please update your question with build configuration, Visual Studio version, threading, a [mcve] and so on.

Comment: @CodeCaster It's hard to provide a verifiable example, because the same code doesn't produce this problem in the same solution lol

Comment: Well it's still Visual Studio, so did you try cleaning your solution, deleting bin and obj and restarting Visual Studio?

Comment: @CodeCaster Let's try, it would be wonderful that this could solve the issue lol

Comment: @CodeCaster About the type thing, `TSourceItem` is `item.GetType()` 100%.

Comment: @Matias what I mean by that if `TSourceItem` is `Foo`, but `item` actually is a `Bar` that implicitly converts to `Foo` but returns a `null`, then you could see this behavior as well. Anyway see also [Visual Studio 2015 debugger showing null when object is not null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37411105/visual-studio-2015-debugger-showing-null-when-object-is-not-null), [Visual Studio debugger shows wrong value (null where there should be a value)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33659922/), and so on. You're not alone.

Comment: @CodeCaster Yeah, I got it. I mean that `TSourceItem` could be a type `A` and items are also `A`. I see that hopefully I'm not alone, I was going to shot my head :D (

Comment: @CodeCaster Cleaning the solution and restarting Visual Studio didn't solve the issue. BTW, I'll try to fix the actual issue in my project because it's very clear that `item` isn't `null`... In the mean time, let's see if I find what's also causing the `null` thing!

Comment: @CodeCaster *“but `item` actually is a `Bar` that implicitly converts to `Foo` but returns a `null`”* – The compiler ensures at compile time that items in the hash set can be assigned to `TSourceItem item`. There’s no implicit type conversion here since the type of the collection is already generic.

Comment: @poke That's it. BTW, it's true that there're some use cases where what CodeCaster says happens that implicit conversion

Comment: @poke http://ideone.com/mo8pbB

Comment: @CodeCaster BTW it's not my case

Comment: @CodeCaster But there, the conversion to `null` happens *before* the loop, when the `new Bar()` is added to the list. This is a completely separate and unrelated issue to this question. OP showed that the collection he is iterating over contains non-null elements, so after that (since the collection is generic), the compiler ensures that the assignment in the loop works and `item` cannot become `null` implicitly.

Comment: @poke you're right about that. I think we already established this is a debugger issue, I just commented on a possible cause for an item to be null while iterating, while it isn't null in the source collection. Of course if the iteration type and collection type are the same, that isn't possible. Edit: nevermind, you can't create a conversion to a base class of course.